# Extract an array from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Before I start sorry for my English, my poor python knowledge (newbie)  and a possible duplicate question. I tried and searched a lot but couldn't find any solution to the problem that I got stuck. Here is the problem;

I have an array named array1 that is loaded with `numpy.loadtxt()` it is a text file that has 2 columns of data with `x` and `y`. `x` range from 0.4 to 15. the increment is not problem.

I also have a second array `array2` which contains `x'` values range from `10` to `12`.

Note: The increment of `x`in each array is different. I will use them for linear interpolation for `y` values later.

I want to crop the first array by using the second array `x'` values range 10 to 12 .
I tried this;

```
new_array = array1[(array1>=np.amin(array2)) * (array1<= np.amax(array2))]
```

It crops the first array (`array1`). But I can only extract  x values.

```
[ 10.   10.1  10.2  10.3  10.4  10.5  10.6  10.7  10.8  10.9  11.   11.1
11.2  11.3  11.4  11.5  11.6  11.7  11.8  11.9  12.   12.1  12.2  12.3
12.4  12.5  12.6  12.7  12.8  12.9]
```

I want to extract the values of `x` and `y` from `array1` by a given range of `x` values from another array.

**Edit**

```
array1[[  0.3     0.302   0.304   0.306   0.308   0.31    0.312   0.314   0.316
...   13.4    13.5    13.6    13.7    13.8    13.9    14.     14.1
14.2    14.3    14.4    14.5    14.6    14.7    14.8    14.9    15.   ]
[  8.82     9.       9.18     9.35     9.52     9.69     9.85    10.02
10.18    10.35    10.52    10.67    10.82    10.97    11.12    11.25
11.39    11.52 …................... 2.3044   1.7773   2.271    2.721 ]]


array2 = [[ 10.    10.02  10.03  10.04  10.05  10.06  10.07  10.08  10.09  10.1
10.12  10.13  10.14  10.15  10.16  10.17  10.18  10.19  10.2   10.21
10.22  10.23  10.24  10.25  10.26  10.27  10.28  10.29  10.3   10.31
10.33  10.34  10.35  10.36  10.37  10.38  10.39  10.4   10.41  10.42
10.43  10.44  10.45  10.46  10.47  10.48  10.49  10.5   10.51  10.52
10.53  10.54  10.59  10.64  10.7   10.75  10.8   10.85  10.9   10.95  11.
11.05  11.1   11.15 ......   12.64  12.65  12.66  12.67  12.68  12.69
12.7   12.71  12.72  12.73  12.74  12.75  12.76  12.77  12.78  12.79
12.8   12.81  12.82  12.83  12.84  12.85  12.86  12.87  12.88  12.89
12.9 ][ 0.0058  0.0073  0.0081  0.0088  0.0096  0.0104  0.0112  0.012   0.0128
0.0136  0.0165  0.0018  0.0195  0.021   0.0226  0.0241  0.0256  0.0272
0.0288  0.0334 ….  0.1092  0.0879  0.0667  0.0458  0.0433  0.0409
0.0385  0.0361  0.0337  0.0314  0.0291  0.0268  0.0245  0.0223  0.0209
0.0195  0.0182  0.0168  0.0155  0.0141  0.0128  0.0115  0.0101  0.0088
0.0085  0.0081  0.0078  0.0074  0.0071  0.0068  0.0064  0.0061  0.0058
0.0054]]
```

Again sorry for my English.  I hope I succeded in explaining myself

Thank you a lot for your helps :)

Comment: Can you show (part of) `array1`? And perhaps for `array2` as well? Because you do `(array1>=np.amin(array2))`, which suggests that `array1` is not a recarray as I would expect (that is, I'd thought you'd need `array1['x'] >= np.min(array2)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the first index corresponds to `x`, this may work:

```
indices = (array1[0,...] >= np.min(array2[0,...])) & (array1[0,...] <= np.max(array2[0,...]))
xselected = array1[0,indices]
yselected = array1[1,indices]
```

Notes: do not use `np.amin`, but `np.min` instead. Do not combine the indices together with a `*`, but use the boolean *and*: `&`.

I've indexed the arrays with `array[0,...]`, but I think you can just use `array[0]` there as well, since the `0` indexes the first dimension.